# Merging multiple workbooks into single sheet in current workbook with the latest data only

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have many excel files(not with the same name) and I need to merge all of those into 1 sheet of current workbook with VBA code. All those files have multiple sheets and only one sheet is common - named LA Work Doc.. For all the workbooks, the header is constant.
Let's say my files are File12032020, File14062020 and File20082020. In all these files, on column A, there are some document codes that are unique. On column D, there is the date when the information about a specific document was updated(but there are not only dates.. there are some N/A and TBCs also that I need to keep). A code can be in File12032020 and in File20082020, but with different date on column D.  When I merge all of those files into 1 master file, I want to show only the latest data(only the information that was updated most recently).

The code that I used to merge all the workbooks into 1 sheet is the following:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim CurrentBook As Workbook
Dim WS As Worksheet
Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LA Work Doc. ")
Dim IndvFiles As FileDialog
Dim FileIdx As Long
Dim i As Integer, x As Integer

Set IndvFiles = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
With IndvFiles
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Title = "Multi-select target data files:"
    .ButtonName = ""
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add ".xlsm files", "*.xlsm"
    .Show
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For FileIdx = 1 To IndvFiles.SelectedItems.Count
    Set CurrentBook = Workbooks.Open(IndvFiles.SelectedItems(FileIdx))
    For Each Sheet In CurrentBook.Sheets
        If Sheet.Name = "LA Work Doc. " Then
            Dim LRow1 As Long
            LRow1 = WS.Range("A" & WS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Dim LRow2 As Long
            LRow2 = CurrentBook.ActiveSheet.Range("A" & CurrentBook.ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
            Dim ImportRange As Range
            Set ImportRange = CurrentBook.ActiveSheet.Range("A5:AD" & LRow2)
            ImportRange.Copy
            WS.Range("A" & LRow1 + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        End If
    Next Sheet
    CurrentBook.Close False
Next FileIdx

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Can anyone help me with this thing?

Thank you.

Comment: Your loop refers to `Sheet` but you don't use this inside your loop at all so you are always referring to the same sheet (the active sheet).

Comment: @SJR I managed to solve the problem with the sheets. Now it's working even if the files have multiple sheets. I still can't figure out the problem with deleting the duplicates by date. Because column D doesn't have only date, it also have some N/A and TBCs that I need to keep...

Comment: You could add a helper colums with 1 for the latest date or NA etc and then filter on that and delete all the other rows.

Comment: **Cool**: The For Each loop and the following IF statement are actually not 'necessary', You could just use `Set Sheet = CurrentBook.Worksheets("LA Work Doc. ")` instead since you know there is a worksheet named "LA..." in the workbook. But one can never be too sure, so you would have to implement some error handling. But if you leave the code as is, there will be no errors, it will 'just' loop through the sheets in vain. A good idea would be to put `Exit For` before `End If` to stop looping when worksheet is found.

Comment: Since you are copying values, a better way would be to instead of `ImportRange.Copy: WS.Range("A" & LRow1 + 1)...` use the one-liner `WS.Range("A" & LRow1 + 1).Resize(ImportRange.Rows.Count, ImportRange.Columns.Count).Value = ImportRange.Value`. Now if you could clarify more precisely what of the data you want to keep i.e.1. the latest value in each workbook or 2. the latest value of all the workbooks meaning that there will be only one value per unique document code.

Comment: @VBasic2008 it would be the latest value of all workbooks.. It needs to be only one value per unique document code.. I was thinking I could create a command button to remove the dublicates after all the data is in one workbook

Comment: Let's say the most recent date is most recent. But what about `N/A` and `TBCs` or anything else? Do you have a list of the hierarchy of the possible strings? Or is the hierarchy determined by the order of the files somehow? What should happen if two same dates for a code have been found?

Comment: @VBasic2008 So the possible strings are TBC, #N/A and #REF! and I need to keep those ones. Else, if it's a date, I should keep the latest. It's not possible to be the same date for a code. Those files are made for each week so the date is different and usually it appears TBC, #N/A or REF! if the check on that document was made but ultimately did not go ahead.  But they may happen in the future so I will need the data for these to be included